# Lookup element in python list using each value from another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've tried for in loops, while true loops, next, etc. Either I get information repeated over and over, or the loop does not start over once it finds an element. I've also searched on SO and google for a solution but without success.

What I am trying to do is this:

```
for feature in parJson:
    ids = feature['properties']['id']
    event = feature['properties']['event']
    headline = feature['properties']['headline']
    expires = feature['properties']['expires']
    areaDesc = feature['properties']['areaDesc']
    geoCodes = feature['properties']['geocode']['UGC']

    states = alerts.getZones(geoCodes)

def getZones(self, getZones):
    zones = json.loads(open("resources/zones.json").read())
    parsedZones = zones['features']
    #TODO figure out how to compare this list!
    states = []
    for ugcCode in getZones:
        ugcCode = str(ugcCode)
        for element in parsedZones:
            ugc = element['properties']['id']
            state = element['properties']['state']
            if ugc == ugcCode:
                states.append(state)
                break

    print(states)
```

getZones is a list of UGC geocode zones. parsedZones is a json list of watches warnings advisories from api.weather.gov/alerts/active.

And the data:

the parsedZones: https://api.weather.gov/zones (downloaded to disk because it is so large)

the parJson: https://api.weather.gov/alerts/active

From the list of active alerts, I get the ugc codes the warning is valid for. The api does not give the state, only those codes. So I need to decode the codes into state names. I already have a dictionary with state names/abbreviations. What I need is a python set of the unique states based off the UGC codes listed in the warning. Once I have the states, I can lookup each state name using its abbreviation, then display the state. So it would go like this:

Let's say a warning is valid for Texas and Oklahoma. And the codes provided are OKC001, and TXC001. I can't just use startswith to get the first two letters, because some areas don't start with the state abbreviation. Therefore, I must use a zones list provided by the api, which I downloaded to my server. I need to lookup each code provided one at a time and retrieve the two letter abbreviation. I can work with it after I get that. But I can't seem to get it to work. The goal is to add each state abbreviation to a set to get unique values.

The end result of what I have done so far is this:

```
[] None
Severe Thunderstorm Watch
Windsor; Orange; Rutland
[] None [] None
Flood Warning
DeKalb; Marshall
['IN', 'IN', 'IN'] None
Special Weather Statement
Miami; Wabash; Huntington
['PA', 'PA', 'PA'] None
Special Weather Statement
Wyoming; Lackawanna; Luzerne
[] None
Flood Advisory
Sequoyah
['NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY'] None
Special Weather Statement
Onondaga; Madison; Northern Oneida; Southern Oneida; Cortland; Otsego; Chenango
```

Comment: Each time you loop in the "for" loop, you overwrite the info from the previous run. This code will set all of those variables as the ones corresponding to the last value it looked at.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I have also tried this without setting any variables with the same result. Essentially, I end up with some rows with the states listed and some rows with no states listed. I'm guessing this is caused by the overwriting..?

Comment: What is the output you would like?

Comment: The end goal is to have: Texas, Oklahoma displayed on the page. 

Ideally, I would have a list like so: ['TX', 'OK'] that I can then use to retrieve the state names from a dictionary that looks like {'Texas': 'TX', 'Oklahoma': 'OK'}

So basically: ['TXC001', 'OKC001'] then that would give me

['TX', 'OK'] then

['Texas', 'Oklahoma'] from which I can print

Texas, Oklahoma

And it would do this per alert. Some alerts have mulitple UGC codes listed for the same state, so after I got the state abbreviations, I know I can use a set to get the unique values.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the loop is resulting in all of the variables being overwritten for each element you're looping through.

```
states = []
for feature in parJson:
    ...
    states.append(alerts.getZones(geoCodes))
print(states)
```

This will result in a list of the states in question. You may want to store this info all in a nested dictionary with each state being a key and the various items you want to know being lists that you append if you have additional information instead of overwriting...

Comment: Thank you, I will try this after lunch and let you know what happens.

Comment: Okay, so I have to print the states inside the loop, because the loop also renders an html template. But, I went ahead and added the list to the class method. What I get is essentially what I've got before. It prints no states for most elements. Only printing them sometimes. I'll update my question to show what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I had uploaded a new file with the zones but it didn't actually overwrite the old file. Used wget to retrieve the file and it solved the problem. Thank you to @mauve for their suggestion. It did help with my issue once I got the correct data.